# Dispersing a static field from a touch circuit - escape room

Tags: microcontroller

I run an escape room, inside a puzzle we have is where players need to hold hands and touch 2 screws to complete a circuit and trigger a switch.

I don't have the exact specs, but it's going to look something like this:
https://www.frightprops.com/human-circuit-puzzle.html

It sits in a wooden box (2x2x4).  It was working fine during the summer. 
The problem is, since winter time, the trigger will go off just by walking next to it.  Alternatively, you can touch the wooden box to make it go off as well.

So, I could try and ground it (im not sure if this particular controller has a ground - (cheap chinese box)...but I was wondering if there is a way to just reset it back to how it was.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Given what you write I'd guess it uses a MOSFET and that the colder wintertime lets more static build up on humans walking around the place. This tells me this is a cheesy design that isn't well-managed to measure actual conduction of a current, but instead depends upon applying a voltage via humans to a FET gate. Should have been differently designed. I fear we'd need a schematic to do much good for you. Otherwise, we'd just need to do a new design you'd have to build.

Comment: Maybe the humidity in the room changes the dielectric of the air. Increasing ESD. Check the humidity, possibly install a humidifier.

Answer (score 0):

There's a > 50% chance that you can fix this with a 1 MOhm resistor between each screw and the negative battery/power supply terminal of the lock box. If this somehow makes the device no longer function with contact, try 4.7 MOhm.

The theory is that the lock box capacitive sensor is measuring against ground, which is a common case, and that the static build-up needs to be dissipated there. Human skin contact resistance is usually well below a megaohm, so the magnitude of the bleed resistor seems to be big enough to not interfere too much with the circuit.

You should be able to jerry rig this with some solder, or just some conductive glue, and some bent-wire resistors from Fry's or Digi-Key or your old forgotten electronics experimenter's kit :-)

Comment: I'll give this a try - thanks!  - Humidifier is my next go to.